# Setting a "hard-coded" flag in sources during build process

Tags: groovy, gradle, continuous-integration

I am developing a (Groovy) application that I build via Gradle (on a Continuous Integration server). That application should be compiled into two versions: one development build (including some features I only want to enable for myself), and one public build (which would not include or just disable those "development features").

One solution to this would be to have something like a global flag directly in the main class of the application, something like `static final boolean PUBLIC_RELEASE`. Then within my code I could check for that flag and enable or disable a certain feature.

Now in my Gradle build script I could check for an environment variable (set by the Continuous Integration server). If that variable is set, then I could set (i.e. change) the current value of the flag to either `true` or `false` before the sources are being compiled.

I am sure that approach would work. However, it does not feel right to modify the sources themselves during the build process. On the other hand I would assume this is kind of a standard task for many software projects.

Is there any "best practice" to deal with this requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is can work out three way for handling the scenario - ordered in the way I would do that:

1. Create a dedicated *properties* file the is filtered during build and added to the final jar. Application behavior is determined by this file on runtime. Basically this is how such scenario is handled, but such file can be modified in jar directly by the user.
2. Source code filtering, hint [ReplaceTokens](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:copying_files). This seems the best way of securing the application, since the behavior is *compiled* into code directly, but also problematic when it comes to filtering.
3. Configure the behavior of application by passing system properties `-D` at runtime. There's a possibility that a lot of such properties should be passed so it might be problematic for the end user and the configuration of the application is explicitly exposed.

Comment: Well, I don't want to users to be able to enable those hidden features. So it seems options 1 and 3 are not a solution to my requirement.

Comment: That's what I thought. So it seems the one You can use is source code filtering.

Comment: @Matthias, if the question is answered please accept the answer.

Comment: Well, I was still waiting for more replies, maybe there are other approaches/ideas as well. But if you insist ...

Comment: I guess that there might be no other answers unfortunately :/